# Why $\frac{{\partial D}}{{\partial x}}$ and $\frac{{\partial D}}{{\partial y}}$ don't have any common factor?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, partial-derivative, algebraic-curves

Let

- ${A_j} \in {\mathbb{C}^{n \times n}},0<{w_j}\in \mathbb{R} (j = 0,1,2....m)$ and $\lambda $ is a complex variable such that $\lambda=x+iy$ and  $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$.
- ${\rm{P(}}\lambda {\rm{) = }}{{\rm{A}}_m}{\lambda ^m} + .....{A_1}\lambda  + {A_0}$ is a matrix polynomial.
- ${\rm{Q(}}\lambda {\rm{) = }}{{\rm{w}}_m}{\lambda ^m} + .....{w_1}\lambda  + {w_0}$
- t=$Q{(\left| \lambda  \right|)^2}$
- $T(x,y)=\det (tI - P{(\lambda )^*}P(\lambda )) $

It's not hard to prove that  :
$T(x,y)= \sqrt {{x^2} + {y^2}} p(x,y) + q(x,y),$ Where $p,q$ are polynomials.

Now let
$$D(x,y)= ( {{x^2} + {y^2}}) p(x,y)^2 - q(x,y)^2.$$

Why  $\frac{{\partial D}}{{\partial x}}$ and $\frac{{\partial D}}{{\partial y}}$  don't have any common factor?(Else trivial factor)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1752977/a-question-on-polynomials.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the following, whilst not an exhaustive answer may provide some insight or build a picture as to why there is a non-trivial factor in both derivatives.

Set
\begin{align}
T(x, y)            &= \sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}p(x, y)+q(x, y) \\
\overline{T}(x, y) &= \sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}p(x,y)-q(x, y)
\end{align}
It is clear that
$$D(x, y) \equiv T \overline{T}$$
Thus
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial D}{\partial x} &= \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left( T \overline{T}\right) \\
                              &=\frac{\partial T}{\partial x}\overline{T}+T \frac{\partial \overline{T}}{\partial x} \\
\text{Clearly}\quad \frac{\partial D}{\partial y} 
                              &=\frac{\partial T}{\partial y}\overline{T}+T \frac{\partial \overline{T}}{\partial y}
\end{align}

Comment: I edited this post, but 
I don't understand, why $∂D/∂x$ and $∂D/∂y$ have not any common factor?